# ¿Qué se pela cuando hace "un frío que pela"?

Tags: expresiones, tiempo-meteorológico

Buscando el origen de la expresión *hace un frío [que pela](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SMzsNUr#2yxcSp1)* he llegado a ver algunas páginas más o menos respetables que cuentan una historia acerca de una expedición al Annapurna en 1950 en la que por el frío intenso unas almendras resultaron más fáciles de pelar que de costumbre.

Buscando un poco más, en la hemeroteca he encontrado de hecho casos de la expresión hasta en el siglo XVIII:

> *Yo no quiero levantarme,
>
> ni a estas horas salir fuera;
>
> que son las doce no mas,
>
> y hace un frío que pela.*
>
> **Diario curioso, histórico, erudito, comercial, civil y económico.** 24/12/1772, [página 3](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003949448&page=3&search=%22que%20pela%22&lang=es).

Queda descartada pues la explicación de otras fuentes. Pero entonces, ¿qué es realmente lo que se pela cuando hace un frío que pela? ¿Desde cuándo se usa la expresión?

Dato curioso: la expresión entró en el DLE en 1970 (muy reciente en comparación), y curiosamente con la posibilidad de poderse aplicar tanto a cosas frías como calientes, con el significado de "que producen una sensación extremada". Cita como ejemplo: "esta sopa está que pela".

Comment: ¿La piel? En ingles hay una expresión: `winter rash` que define los desagradables cambios de la piel durante el invierno.

Comment: We also have in British English the word gooseflesh for the sensation of your hairs standing on end due to cold or fear. Perhaps the sensation described here is similar?

Comment: @mdewey we have the expressions "piel de gallina" or "[carne de gallina](https://dle.rae.es/?id=7bnjWlr)" for the same purpose.

Comment: En Argentina esta expresión es de la época de mis padres y abuelos y no pensé que sería tan antigua. Siempre la relacioné con el calor y con el agua hirviendo que se usa para aflojar la piel de los tomates, por ejemplo, para quitársela.

Comment: la piel, sobre todo cuando el frio es seco (algo normal cuando el frio esta debajo de los cero grados) y corre viento. 
en estas situaciones el viento helado quema la piel por congelamiento y resequedad.

Answer (score 6):

Buscando información para otra expresión referente al verbo *pelar*, resulta que he encontrado que la expresión *hacer un frío que pela* es como unos 100 años más antigua que el ejemplo del siglo XVIII que puse en la pregunta, solo que se usaba de otra forma:

> *Ayer mañana, día de la Candelaria, amaneció Madrid con una nieve de media vara, y hace un frío que se las pela.*
>
> Jerónimo de Barrionuevo, "Avisos. Tomos I, II, III y IV.", 1654 - 1658 (España).

Esta versión de la expresión aparece ya registrada en el *Autoridades*:

> PELARSELAS. Phrase con que se dá à entender que alguno apetece ò executa alguna cosa con veheméncia, actividad, ò eficacia.

Es decir, la expresión originalmente usaba la forma verbal *pelárselas*, con el mismo significado que se le da hoy día en expresiones como "corre que se las pela", es decir, con el sentido de "hacer algo con vehemencia y eficacia". Así pues, traslado la pregunta para averiguar esto otro:

[¿Qué se pela cuando uno "corre que se las pela"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/29213/12637)

Answer (score 0):

A mi entender, en la expresión "hace un frío que pela" el verbo "pelar" tiene un significado bien concreto, relacionado con el efecto del frío excesivo sobre la piel. Ver las acepciones (2) y (8) del verbo ["pelar"](https://dle.rae.es/pelar). El DLE también aclara:

> que pela
>
> 1. loc. adj. coloq. Que provoca un frío muy intenso. Corre un viento que pela.

El frío excesivo produce la descamación de la piel, como muestra esta foto:

[image: Descamación]