# ¿Qué se pela cuando uno "corre que se las pela"?

Tags: expresiones

Siguiendo con las [preguntas referentes al verbo pelar](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/29197/12637), se me ocurre también preguntar qué se pela cuando uno corre que se las pela.

Según el DLE:

> **[que se las pela](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SMzsNUr#GZPRcKB)**
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. Con gran vehemencia o rapidez. *Corre, escribe, grita que se las pela.*

Esta expresión proviene de esta otra:

> **[pelárselas](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SMzsNUr#2yqTkqC)**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Apetecer algo con vehemencia. *Se las pela por figurar.*

Y aquí viene lo bueno: esta expresión es tan antigua que ya aparece registrada en el *Diccionario de autoridades*.

> PELARSELAS. Phrase con que se dá à entender que alguno apetece ò executa alguna cosa con veheméncia, actividad, ò eficacia.

El diccionario cita además a Quevedo como ejemplo:

> *Isabel, que se las pela,
>
>   soltó la taza y el jarro, [...].*
>
> Francisco de Quevedo y Villegas, "Jácaras", c 1610 - a 1645 (España).

Por tanto, en el siglo XVII ya se usaba la expresión. Ahora bien, ¿qué se pela cuando alguien *se las pela*?

Comment: ¿Qué se pela? En el caso de las avestruces, [son las patas](https://www.1000chistes.com/chiste/sin-plumas-en-las-patas).

Answer (score 1):

'Pelarse' es también es una forma coloquial de decir 'escapar' , por lo que 'Corre que se nos pela' también significa 'Corre que se nos escapa' , y puede referirse a un ladrón , el autobús, un vuelo de avión, etc. por lo que aquello que se pela, es aquello que se está persiguiendo.

Comment: "Pelar/se", por escapar, no es reconocible en Castellano de España, en donde, por otro lado, coloquialmente tiene sentido de pasar frio.

Answer (score 0):

La definición más ovbia sería que de tanto correr, se ha deshecho el calzado.

Puede entonces pelarse la suela del calzado o la misma planta de los pies.

Según la [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SMAAyb8%7CSMAKBJW) "pela" puede referirse también a pelea/paliza (dejo aquí un curioso [poema](https://www.buscapalabra.com/definiciones.html?palabra=pela) que emplea la palabra "pela") y a peseta, la antigua moneda de España.

Yo no descartaría que en su origen la frase fuera distinta y se refiriera al dinero que se pierde, algo así como "corre que el dinero vuela".

Sin embargo, la primera opción me parece la más simple, y como dijo el amigo [Okham](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navaja_de_Ockham), la teoría más simple tiene más probabilidades de ser correcta que la compleja.

Comment: Ten en cuenta que "corre que se las pela" es solo una forma de usar la expresión. Ya en la pregunta comento que la expresión proviene de "pelárselas", que de hecho se usaba en el siglo XVII en expresiones como "hace un frío que se las pela", y no creo que el frío deshaga el calzado. También tienes el ejemplo de "Isabel, que se las pela, soltó la taza y el jarro" en el sentido de "lo hizo rápida y eficazmente", que tampoco creo que haga referencia al calzado, ni tampoco al dinero como dices.

Comment: @Charlie, además, creo que *pela* se ha usado solo como sinónimo de *peseta* (no de *dinero* en general. Y la peseta se empieza a acuñar en el siglo XIX.

Comment: @Charlie Nunca he oído ni leído "que se las pela" para el frío sino ["que pela"](https://dle.rae.es/?id=SMzsNUr).